# Core Data, deleting a managed object's effect on the objects "superView"

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a managed object that is in a "to-many" relationship to other sub managed objects. When I delete one of the sub managed objects, the array on the main managed object that represents the relationship to the sub managed objects is emptied.

Below is a log of what happens when I fetch a subManaged object and delete it. I would have expected the result of the operation to be that the .subMO array's count to be 1.

```
    NSLog(@"%d", superViewMO.subMO.count); //this gives 2

    NSLog(@"%d", fetchedSubMOArray.count); //this gives 1

    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[fetchedSubMOArray objectAtIndex:0]];

     NSLog(@"%d", superViewMO.subMO.count); //this gives 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found out the reason.** I had accidentally set the relationship from the subManagedObject to the superview as having the delete rule of Cascade. I was actually deleting the superView allong with the subView I think. Changing it to Nullify produces the expected performance.